# How to Change ImageView background from a file when click on it?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to change the image of ImageView when  click on it.The file path is correct But when run this method stop application.When the debug app file variable contain this path: /storage/emulated/0/nabege/images/1442670759552.jpg .

I use this code:

```
btn_showImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
    + "/nabege" + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + imageFileName);
    try {
        btn_showImage.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Please advice.

Comment: what is `btn_showImage` in your code?? is it a button or imagview?

Comment: Is the file format is important? I tried a variety of formats.Only accepts JPEG format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Bitmap

```
btn_showImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/nabege" + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + imageFileName);
         try {
                if(file.exists())
                {
                  Bitmap image_bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                  btn_showImage.setImageBitmap(image_bmp);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: I use way and change one line like this :                                             Bitmap image_bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());                    But dont work

Comment: check it now,its Actually `file.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: I use this code .String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/nabege" + File.separator
      + "images" + File.separator + imageFileName;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
    btn_showImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  Now size of imageview changed But image of imageview has not changed

Comment: I check when debug app .Path of file is /storage/emulated/0/nabege/images/1442726244848.JPEG .Is it true?

Comment: I found the root of the problem. I had saved images via mobile phone camera. The size of images is high. Because of the high resolution images are not displayed in  imageview.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is your minimum and target SDKs? You may need to add either the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE (which grants the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission implicitly) in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

See:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: My project have this Permissions.   <uses-sdk         android:minSdkVersion="11"         android:targetSdkVersion="19" />